# Storing items within a dictionary to be then used to calculate area

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python (2 days) and I'm struggling to find a solution to add a variable to a dictionary with a defined value as well as

```html
 choice = input("")
    if choice == "1":
        print ("1.Basic - £8")
        print ("2.Standard- £13")
        print ("3.Premium- £25")




        Premium = dict(name ="Premium",
                       Cost = 25.0)

        Standard = dict(name ="Standard",
                       Cost = 13.0)

        Basic = dict(name ="Basic",
                       Cost = 8.0)



        Grass_Dict = {}


        Premium = input("Type Premium")


        Basic = print(input("Type '3' for Basic")

        Grass_Dict['1'] = Premium


        Grass_Dict['2'] = Standard



        Grass_Dict['3'] = Basic
```

I have then tried to add the variables to the second part of the code so that when I reference the cost calculation I will be able to use the stored variable and it's value (25.0) to be used.

elif (choice =="2"):

```
  time.sleep(0.2)
print("-")

time.sleep(0.2)
print("-")

print("2.Select Area of Grass")
print("1.Select Shape Required")

if (choice =="1"):
        print("Grass Calculation Program")
        print("Select Shape Required")
        print("1.Square")
        print("2.Triangle")
        print("3.Circle")


shape = input ("Please Select (1/2/3)")

if choice =="1":
    length = input ("Please Enter Length")
    width = input ("Please Enter Width")
    area = (length*width)


    print ("Calculating Cost")


elif choice =="2":
    length = input ("Please Enter Length")
    width = input ("Please Enter Width")
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It doesn't look like you have asked a question.  As it is it isn't clear what you are asking. You will get better results if you can narrow down your question to a single problem.  Please read [mcve] and [ask].  Please try to ensure that the indentation is correct for the code you post.  If you ask questions about code the throws and error/exception post the complete Traceback.

Comment: Read about [python-dictionary-quick-guide](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-dictionary-quick-guide)